# Use SharePoint web app without user profile service application

Tags: 2010, user-profile-service, display-name

I have a requirement to allow users to change their display name, but, due to a somewhat bizarre combination of existing farm configuration and other limitations, I cannot accomplish this by making the "Name" property in the User Profile Service app editable.

I think my best option is to not use a UPSA at all with this web app and create a web part to allow the user to set their own username. This web app only has one site collection.

I have already created a very simple web part as a proof of concept.

Are there any issues I should be concerned with?

*Other possible solutions I have rejected:
Custom Membership provider - too much effort
Multiple User Profile Service Applications - not possible, only a single WFE in this farm.

Answer (score 0):

Generally this is accomplished by providing a mechanism to the user to update their name in the system of record for the UPA. (Usually AD, though you should consider the governance of such a solution.)

Comment: Yes, however, due to the existing farm configuration that is not possible. Specifically, this is a farm with a single SharePoint server (distinct SQL backend), and two web apps. The "main" web app should never have its display name editable, while "my" web app should. You cannot have two UPSA on a single server (well, you can, but it won't work right due to only one User Profile Synch Service per server and the one-to-one mapping between UPSA and UPSS).

Comment: No, I am talking about writing a custom control to update AD not the User Profile. There is no SharePoint restriction on this approach. I don't understand why you would want two UPAs for your farm.

Comment: Ah, I misread your response. Unfortunately, since some users are users of both web apps, changing the display name in AD would change the display name in both web apps. The purpose of having two UPSA was for the updated display name to be stored in the UPSA's data store, or, to use a different field in AD to store the DisplayName for use in "my" web app.